# How to start running a script from the middle based on a condition in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a script which takes a huge amount of time to run, and some of the results generated might not be satisfactory, and we might need to rerun parts of the script.

So I have given the option for quitting the program wherever needed and I save all the workspace variables to a file. But when the user later runs the script again, I don't want the script to run from the beginning. I want to ask the user how far they have progressed, and just continue from there.

A possible solution would be to use goto, which doesn't exist in MATLAB (and I personally don't like using it if I can avoid it). Are there any other solutions possible?

My script basically combines a lot of other scripts. I would like to give the user the option to choose which script to start from. Here is the code if required:-

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

disp('This is a script to do the back projection for an event given the required input files.');
disp('Please make sure you have copied all of the following files into the ./back_projection/data directory:-');
disp(' ');
disp('1. V_{array}.txt - File containing the velocity data of all the stations selected from the array in one single column');
disp('2. T_{array}.txt - FIle containing the corresponding time data for rall the stations selected from the array in one single column');
disp('3. P_time_{array} - File containing the P wave arrival time of the event at all all the selected stations of the array');
disp('4. stnlat_{array} - File containing the station latitudes of all the stations selected from the array');
disp('5. stnlong_{array} - File containing the station longitudes of all the stations selected from the array');
disp('6. data_info_{array}.txt - File containing the GCARC, AZ and BAZ of the event at all the stations selected from the array');
disp(' ');
input('Continue? (After making sure, press enter)','s');

%% Starting back projection
delete array.txt;
cd back_projection;
gridgen;
save vars;
opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
if(opts=='y')
    return
end
clear;
load vars;
o='y';
a_arr = [];
increment = 0;
while(strcmpi(o,'y'))
    array = input('Enter array: ','s');
    disp(' ');
    disp('Station Check...');
    station_check;
    save vars;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end
    clear;
    load vars;
    increment = increment+1;
    a_arr = [a_arr;array];
    disp(' ');
    disp('Cross Correlation...');
    Crosscorrelation;
    save vars;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end
    clear;
    load vars;
    disp(' ');
    disp('Back Projection...')
    rupture_back_projection;
    save vars;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end
    clear;
    load vars;
    o = input('Do you want to enter more arrays (y/n)? ','s');

end

cd ..;
fid = fopen('array.txt','w');
for j = 1:increment
    fprintf(fid,'%s \n',a_arr(j,:));
end
fclose(fid);
cd back_projection;
%%
disp(' ');
disp('Aligning all the arrays...');
net_stack_align;
save vars;
opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
if(opts=='y')
    return
end
clear;
load vars;
%%
input('Close the plot and press enter');
disp(' ');
disp('Doing a cumulative plot of the energy in the provided time window...');
start_win = input('Enter the starting time of the window: ');
end_win = input('Enter the closing the of the window: ');
cumulative_plot(b_corr,e_lat,e_long,start_win,end_win,ev_lat,ev_long);
input('Close the plot and press enter');
save vars;
opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
if(opts=='y')
    return
end
clear;
load vars;
%%
disp(' ');
disp('Plotting the energy peak at all points in time (secs) within the time window...');
end_win = input('Enter the closing time of the window (window starts from 1 second): ');
peak_time_wise(b_corr,e_lat,e_long,end_win,ev_lat,ev_long);
input('Close the plot and press enter');
save vars;
opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
if(opts=='y')
    return
end
clear;
load vars;

disp(' ');
disp('Saving movie frames ...');
movie_slices(b_corr, e_lat, e_long, bp_l, bp_u);
disp('Saved');
save vars;
opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
if(opts=='y')
    return
end
clear;
load vars;
%%
disp(' ');
disp('Running a movie test');
frameskip = input('Enter the number of frames to skip for testing: ');
movie_test(b_corr,e_lat,e_long,bp_l,bp_u,frameskip);
input('Close the plot and press enter');
save vars;
opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
if(opts=='y')
    return
end
clear;
load vars;

%% Miscellaneous Calculations
disp(' ');
disp('Back Projection has been done. Starting miscellaneous calculations.');
disp('STF calculation...');
o='y';

while(strcmpi(o,'y'))
    array=input('Enter the array: ','s');
    stack_plot;
    movefile(fullfile('output',['stack_uncorr_',num2str(bp_l),'_',num2str(bp_u),'Hz_',array,'.txt']),fullfile('output',['stack_uncorr_',num2str(bp_l),'_',num2str(bp_u),'Hz_',array,'_stf.txt']));
    movefile(fullfile('output',['stack_corr_',num2str(bp_l),'_',num2str(bp_u),'Hz_',array,'.txt']),fullfile('output',['stack_corr_',num2str(bp_l),'_',num2str(bp_u),'Hz_',array,'_stf.txt']));
    save vars;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end
    clear;
    load vars;
    o=input('Do you want to enter more arrays? (y/n) ','s');
end
STF_calc;
input('Close the plot and press enter');
save vars;
opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
if(opts=='y')
    return
end
clear;
load vars;
%%
disp(' ');
disp('Plotting earthquake traces...');
o='y';
while(strcmpi(o,'y'))
    array=input('Enter the array: ','s');
    stack_plot;
    trace_plot;
        save vars;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end
    clear;
    load vars;
    o=input('Do you want to enter more arrays? (y/n) ','s');
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% To add any additional scripts, put the scripts in the './back_projection'
% directory  and then insert the script call in this section below.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
disp(' ');
disp('Process completed');
cd ..;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something along the lines of

```
c = input('Which script?');
switch c
case -1
    % first script
case 0
    % second script
case 1
   % third Script
otherwise
   % fourth script
end
```

If you do not do this, you can also just block comment some code out in Matlab.

```
%{
    Stuff to be commented out
%}
```